# Can we start Java Jframe program in DOS mode

Tags: java, swing, jsp, servlets

I have following `JForm` in Java dynamic application and I need to download some files for which I don't want to display it in GUI, I want the program to run through command line.

Can we do it in the same form or we need to create a seperate desktop application for it?

Here is the code..

```
  public class LoginForm extends javax.swing.JFrame
  {

   \\some other code

   \\ main function of form

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
      public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            if(args.length > 0)
            {
                setGuiDisplay(1);
                for (String s: args) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            }
            else
            {

            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

     public static void setGuiDisplay(int GuiDisplay) {
        LoginForm.GuiDisplay = GuiDisplay;

        //Start Downloading
         FrmMain frm1=  new FrmMain();
         frm1.StartDownload();
    }
```

Comment: Question is nice, but I wonder why you need GUI based app in CUI? I will be happy if you clear my doubt.

Comment: @GPRathour i want to download the files without user intraction, you mention the files in XML and the tool download it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, never calling `setVisible(true)`, when no GUI code is mixed with the download, like an error message. It might be that progress animation is done, but has no effect, as long nothing is displayed.

It is more a *refactoring problem*, separating the download from the GUI; which would make sense.

For other searchers: Java also can be installed headless, that is: some linux system without GUI, like some minimalistic servers. *There* one might expect a problem.

Comment: Hi @joop thanks for answer, is it possible to display the status of download in 20%,.. ?

Comment: You mean the often seen "10%" backspace³ "11%" and so on. Not that I know of.

Comment: you suggest to build 2 seperate application for it ?

Comment: First separating the old app in GUI classes and separate data (model) class(es) that do the calculation. Rewriting a bit on adding a new feature keeps the code base clean. It could remain the same application probably.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, ya did that

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can download something into your Swing application. You need to have this process running in a seperate thread though.

Have a look at **SwingWorker**. This component will help you design a thread that runs parallel to the operation of the GUI. Or if there is no need to display anything in the GUI after the download, then you could use a standard thread.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but like i want to display 10% complete message in dos mode, how can i achieve it